# list(of t).find(addressOf t) how to pass in arguments?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do something similar to:

```
Sub abcd(s as string)
    listofstuff.find(address of xyz(s))

    ...
End sub

Private Function xyz(th as thing, str as string)
    If th.getName = str Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

The issue I am having is that it will not let me pass in a string. On the MSDN they show a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish by having a variable sit outside of subs as a part of the class, but I was wondering if it is possible to avoid having to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a lambda query?

One match:

```
Dim query = listofstuff.Where(Function(o) o.getName = s).FirstOrDefault
If query IsNot Nothing Then
  'something found
End If
```

All matches:

```
Dim query = listofstuff.Where(Function(o) o.getName = s).ToList
If query.Count > 0 Then
  'something found
End If
```

Comment: it works well if a match is found, but if a match is not found it does not create an instance of the object. How do I check if the object exists after the search?

Comment: thanks... never used isNot before, so I was unfamiliar that such a thing even existed.